# Rstudio can not find "setup" function

Tags: r

its my code :

```
 library(useful)
 nbt.data=read.table("a.txt",sep=",",header=TRUE,row.names=1)

 nbt.data=log(nbt.data+1)

 corner(nbt.data)
         Hi_2338_1  Hi_2338_2 Hi_2338_3 Hi_2338_4 Hi_2338_5
A1BG      2.310553 0.00000000  0.000000 1.0116009         0
A1BG-AS1  0.000000 0.00000000  1.497388 0.3074847         0
A1CF      0.000000 0.04879016  0.000000 0.0000000         0
A2LD1     0.000000 0.00000000  0.000000 0.2546422         0
A2M       0.000000 0.00000000  0.000000 0.0000000         0

 dim(nbt.data)
[1] 23730   301

 nbt=new("seurat",raw.data=nbt.data)

 nbt=setup(nbt,project="NBT",min.cells = 3,names.field = 2,names.delim = "_",min.genes = 1000,is.expr=1,)
Error in setup(nbt, project = "NBT", min.cells = 3, names.field = 2, names.delim = "_",  : 
  could not find function "setup"
```

Comment: Try `nbt= Seurat::Setup(nbt,project="NBT",min.cells = 3,names.field = 2,names.delim = "_",min.genes = 1000,is.expr=1,)`, i.e **capital** S and the name of the package made explicitly. Does this work?

Comment: give this error :Error: 'Setup' is not an exported object from 'namespace:Seurat'

Comment: perhaps i most install Special package for "setup" function. is there such a package or library??

Comment: Run `sessionInfo()` and report your Seurat version please.

Comment: my version is 3.1.5